# Parallelize a simple python script with kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a python script that looks like this:

```
def process_number(num):
    # Do some processing using this number
    print(num)
```

I want to spin up a kubernetes cluster and pass in a range of numbers, and have this script run in parallel across many machines. The number range can be hardcoded. I am unsure how to set up the dockerfile for this application, and how to deploy it to kubernetes, as most of the examples I can find are for web apps.

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/cli/ and https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application

Answer (score 0):

You need a base image that has python. You'll also need to define more of the script to ensure that this function runs over and over again, otherwise, the container will run and end very quickly which leads to crashLoopBackoff.

Before worrying about how to deploy this in kubernetes, you need to make sure you have a working script and that you can [containerize it](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you containerize your application first and ensure it is running well before move to the kubernetes.

You can see some example of how containerize it in theses links:

[Dockerize your Python Application](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application)

[Containerize a Python App in 5 Minutes](https://www.wintellect.com/containerize-python-app-5-minutes/)

After ensure your application in running as expect in a container, them you can move to he next step that is deploy it in kubernetes.

I **strongly** recommend you start with some kubernetes tutorials to understand how the components works and how you can deploy your application. You can use this links:

[Local Development Environment for Kubernetes using Minikube](https://www.abhishek-tiwari.com/local-development-environment-for-kubernetes-using-minikube/)

[Getting Started With Kubernetes #1](https://medium.com/@strebeld/getting-started-with-kubernetes-d9a14955574b)

[Getting Started with Kubernetes #2](https://mrbobbytabl.es/talk/2018_05_ostruct_workshop/)

[Kubernetes: An Introduction](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zrfVlE5r61ZNQrmXKx5gJmBcXnoa_WerHEnTxu5SMco/edit#slide=id.g3cfa019267_4_0)

[kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)

[k8s-intro-tutorials](https://github.com/mrbobbytables/k8s-intro-tutorials)

If you don't have too much time, or you just need something that work for you case, take a look in [Kubernetes Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), you can use your containerize application across multiples replicas.

To expose your service (internally and externally) you could use [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

To test locally you can use the [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) installation on your machine

Hope that helps!